# Comparing treatments when there is imperfect compliance

Tags: causality, instrumental-variables, random-allocation

Imagine a situation where we have a 2x2 cross-randomized program with imperfect compliance to the treatment arms. Thus, units are assigned to treatment A, treatment B, or both treatments. Once they are assigned to either A, B, or both A and B, they can choose whether or not to take up the treatment.

A standard process in such situations is to use treatment offer as an instrument for compliance when calculating the impact of the program (to find the local average treatment effect).

I'd like to know how to compare the effects of treatments A and B if we are faced with a situation where the units that choose to take up the treatments differ in their underlying covariates. Even if the populations assigned to treatments A and B are balanced, it seems as though it could be the case that the groups that take up treatments A and B are unbalanced (e.g. if only educated individuals comply with treatment A and only uneducated individuals comply with treatment B.)

Is there a best practice to follow in such situations (e.g. a particular method of weighting the take-up groups?)